# How to create and append two lists in flutter?

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to append two arrays and create list. I want to append the two list (Background and Sound) and create it as separate list in flutter. I had given the code below.

```
class myModel {
myModel({
required this.bg,
});


List<Background> bg;

factory myModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => myModel(
bg: List<Background>.from(json["Background"].map((x) => Background.fromJson(x))),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
"Background": List<dynamic>.from(Background.map((x) => x.toJson())),
};
}
```

Class for Background

```
class Background {
 Background({
  required this.bUrl,
  required this.song,
 });

String bUrl;
List<Song> song;

factory Background.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Background(
bUrl: json["bURL"],
song: List<Song>.from(json["Song"].map((x) => Song.fromJson(x))),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
"bURL": bUrl,
"Song": List<dynamic>.from(a.map((x) => x.toJson())),
};
}
```

Class for Song

```
class Song {
Song({
required this.id,
required this.sUrl,
});

int id;
String sUrl;

factory Song.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Song(
id: json["id"],
aUrl: json["sURL"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
"id": id,
"sURL": sUrl,
};
}
```

Basically, I want something like :

```
List = [
Background{0, "bg1.mp3"}
Background[0].Song{1, "test.mp3"},
Background[0].Song{2, "test2.mp3"},

Background{1, "bg2.mp3"}
Background[1].Song{1, "test3.mp3"},
]
```

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add two lists in Dart (if they are of the same type) with the plus sign:

```
final result = background + sound;
```

Another way is using the spread operator:

```
final result = [...background, ...sound];
```

You can alsways get an index list with:

```
final resultIndexed = result.asMap().entries;
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I want to add index as well like [bg[0].song{1, ""}]

Comment: is there any way to add like this: 
List = [
Background{0, "bg1.mp3"}
Background[0].Song{1, "test.mp3"},
Background[0].Song{2, "test2.mp3"},

Background{1, "bg2.mp3"}
Background[1].Song{1, "test3.mp3"},
]

Comment: It is most likely not a good idea to create a flat list of both `Background` and `Song` objects. Probably you should map the data when needed. Maybe you should extend your question with what you actually want to accomplish, so we can give a better suggestion on how to approach the problem.

Comment: the background acts like an album, when the user clicks particular background sound, the background sound plays along with the songs which are under that particular background category.

Comment: Then you can simply get the songs from the background object when you are playing them right?